# Filesystemwatcher double entries

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I made a small winforms application to monitor a certain folder for new pdf files, if a new pdf file is created in the particulair folder it will copy it to an other location.

The problem i'm having is that the filesystemwatcher creates double/multiple entries in my listbox, how can i solve this?

```
namespace Scanmonitor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        DateTime lastRead = DateTime.MinValue;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileWatch();
        }

        public void FileWatch()
        {
            watcher.Path = @"C:\Scanner";
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            watcher.Filter = "*.pdf";
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        public void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            scannerListBox.Items.Add(e.FullPath);
            scannerListBox.SelectedIndex = scannerListBox.Items.Count - 1;
            FileMove(scannerListBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }

        public void FileMove(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.Copy(filePath, @"\\share\Data\Scans op OCE 600\" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ToolLabel.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Got it working.

```
public void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            FileInfo objFileInfo = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
            if (!objFileInfo.Exists) return;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

            FileInfo fileinformatie = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
            string strCreateTime = fileinformatie.CreationTime.ToString();
            string strCreateDate = fileinformatie.CreationTime.ToString();

            strCreateTime = strCreateTime.Remove(strCreateTime.LastIndexOf(" "));
            strCreateDate = strCreateDate.Remove(0,strCreateDate.LastIndexOf(" "));

            ProcessAllFiles(e.FullPath, strCreateTime, strCreateDate);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ToolLabel.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ WinApi: ReadDirectoryChangesW() Receiving Double Notifications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036449/c-winapi-readdirectorychangesw-receiving-double-notifications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        FileInfo objFileInfo = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
        if (!objFileInfo.Exists) return;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        FileInfo fileinformatie = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
        string strCreateTime = fileinformatie.CreationTime.ToString();
        string strCreateDate = fileinformatie.CreationTime.ToString();

        //Ignore this, only for my file information.
        strCreateTime = strCreateTime.Remove(strCreateTime.LastIndexOf(" "));
        strCreateDate = strCreateDate.Remove(0,strCreateDate.LastIndexOf(" "));

        ProcessAllFiles(e.FullPath, strCreateTime, strCreateDate);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ToolLabel.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of files (in a collection or dictionary) that already raised an event by the FileSystemWatcher. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Common file system operations might raise more than one event. For example, when a file is moved from one directory to another, several OnChanged and some OnCreated and OnDeleted events might be raised. Moving a file is a complex operation that consists of multiple simple operations, therefore raising multiple events. Likewise, some applications (for example, antivirus software) might cause additional file system events that are detected by FileSystemWatcher.