# In metro, ContentsChanged would be fired twice when QueryOptions' FolderDepth property is set to FolderDepth.Shallow

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I had read the two articles about file system change notification.

[link 1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/winappswithcsharp/thread/7934ba5a-f1fd-445d-9f3b-0012801fe0f4)
[link 2](http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2012/10/03/filesystem-change-notifications/)

ContentsChanged would be fired twice when I set `QueryOptions.FolderDepth` property to `FolderDepth.Shallow` (contrast to `FolderDepth.Deep`).

When creating a new file in the monitored folder, `ContentsChanged` would be fired twice. If deleting one file in the folder, `ContentsChanged` would be fired correctly just once.

It seems a bug.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ WinApi: ReadDirectoryChangesW() Receiving Double Notifications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036449/c-winapi-readdirectorychangesw-receiving-double-notifications)

Comment: Thanks Raymond, I got it. A simple example is, if I create a new file in a monitored folder. Then the folder is also modified. That's why `ContentsChanged` would be fired twice.