# CreateFile fails because of SHARIN_VIOLATION because some other OS process is using it

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have an application where i am using [ReadDirectoryChanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw) to monitor changes in a directory. If any new file gets created or modified or deleted, i will get notification. Once i get the notification, i use the `CreateFile` api to open the file with flag `OPEN_EXISTING`, use the handle to call other windows apis to get file attributes. The way i call `CreateFile`

```
CreateFile(path,GENERIC_READ,
FILE_SHARE_READ,
NULL,
OPEN_EXISTING,
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL ,
NULL );
```

But sometimes, i get `Error 32` which is sharing violation i.e the file is being used by some other process so my application is not able to access.

I added a `sleep` of `100ms` before calling the api and it worked fine as by this time the other process has released the file(or closed handle). But i dont want to add any explicit sleep and i am not sure about the sleep time, it could be different in different environments. This time is based on trial and error

I have also tried to continuously poll/call the `CreateFile` until it succeeds, but it uses up resource and is not a good solution.

Is there any way where i can `wait` on the `CloseHandle`, so that i can the `CreateFile` then or is there any way i can `avoid the error code 32`

Comment: If you only need to get file attributes, use `GetFileAttributes()`, which doesn't care if the file is still in use because it only reads a directory entry.

Comment: I want to be able to call `GetSecurityInfo` along with other attributes, so just `GetFileAttributes` won't suffice for me.

Comment: you mast not use `GENERIC_READ` access in this case - this is your error. use `READ_CONTROL | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` access

Comment: @zett42, the advantage of `GetFileAttributes` is that it's a bit faster since a real File object doesn't have to get allocated and eventually deallocated in the kernel. But if you actually need the File object for subsequent queries, then this is not a useful advantage. In that case RbMm is correct. Shared access only applies to read/execute, write/append, and delete data access; it has no bearing on metadata access.

Comment: Also, using `CreateFile` with `GetFileInformationByHandle[Ex]` and `GetSecurityInfo` allows resolving reparse points (e.g. symlinks, junctions), whereas `GetFileAttributes` and `GetNamedSecurityInfo` query the reparse point itself instead of following it. You can get this behavior with `CreateFile` via the flag `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14040978/17034

Comment: Many, if not most, C/C++ programs share read-write data access for their open files, since it's the default share mode used by the C runtime library. Other than unecessarily requesting generic-read data access instead of just read-attributes and read-control access, it's likely that the OP has caused this sharing violation by not sharing write-data access (e.g. if the file is already open for writing). That only read sharing was requested indicates the OP hasn't read [Creating and Opening Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/creating-and-opening-files).

Comment: @RbMn's suggestion of ddding `READ_CONTROL` instead of `GENERIC_READ` fixed the problem.